# Should I use SHA-1 of App signing key certificate or upload key certificate?

Tags: google-play-services

For Google services configuration, We should create an android credential and set the SHA-1 on the Google Cloud Console.
But on the google docs we found a  conflict, One said to set the SHA-1 of App signing key certificate One said to set upload signing key

When We are setting the SHA-1 of App signing key certificate, The Google services are not working on local APK build, so we don't sure which SHA-1 We need to use.
Our App is Opt-in on google console.